# Can't redirect to another page

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, redirect

I am using this Codeigniter function

```
redirect('home');
```

but it causes me this browser error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

The page can't even get loaded.

My whole function looks like this:

```
public function establish($target) {
    if ($target == 'sender' || $target == 'receiver') {
        $this->validate($target);
        if ($this->validated) {
            if ($target == 'sender') {
                $this->sender_db = $this->session->userdata('sender_db');
                $this->sender_host = $this->session->userdata('sender_host');
                $this->sender_user = $this->session->userdata('sender_user');
                $this->sender_pw = $this->session->userdata('sender_pw');
                if ($this->load->database($this->define_database('sender'))) {
                    $this->err_receiver = 0;
                    return $this->load->database($this->define_database('sender'), TRUE);
                }
                else {
                    $this->err_sender = 1;
                }
            }
            elseif ($target == 'receiver') {
                $this->receiver_db = $this->session->userdata('receiver_db');
                $this->receiver_host = $this->session->userdata('receiver_host');
                $this->receiver_user = $this->session->userdata('receiver_user');
                $this->receiver_pw = $this->session->userdata('receiver_pw');
                if ($this->load->database($this->define_database('receiver'))) {
                    $this->err_receiver = 0;
                    return $this->load->database($this->define_database('receiver'), TRUE);
                }
                else {
                    $this->err_receiver = 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error: illegal parameter. Please use sender or receiver instead.';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'Oops, there is an error! For some reason the property "validated" is not returning true (Connection_model.php)';
            exit;
        }
        redirect('home');
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error: illegal parameter. Please use sender or receiver instead.';
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was running through an endless loop. Two pages were forwarding each other over and over again.